# NameError: name 'decision_alg' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, inteligencia-artificial

```py
from core.modules.bot_module import BotModule
import re, random, os


class BotBrain(BotModule):
    """Esta clase se encarga de aprender y generar texto"""

    def __init__(self, chatbot: object) -> None:
        self.chatbot = chatbot
        self.max_learn_range = 4

        corpus_name = self.chatbot.config["CorpusName"]   
        self.train(corpus_name)

    def add_match(self, text: str, label: str, pattern: str, user_data: dict) -> None:
        match = re.search(pattern, text.lower())
        if match:
            if not label in user_data:
                user_data[label] = []
            user_data[label].append(match.group(1))

            if len(user_data[label]) >= self.max_learn_range:
                user_data[label].pop(0)

    def learn(self, text: str, user_data: dict) -> None:
        for label in self.chatbot.json_dict["patterns"]:
            for pattern in self.chatbot.json_dict["patterns"][label]:
                self.add_match(text.lower(), label, pattern, user_data)

    def replace_labels(self, text: str, label_dict: dict) -> str:
        for label in label_dict:
            text_part = random.choice(label_dict[label])
            pattern = f"{label}|{label.capitalize()}|{label.lower()}"
            text = re.sub(pattern, text_part, text)

        return text

    def train(self, corpus_name: str) -> None:
        model_path = os.path.join(self.chatbot.main_path, "core/save/model.sav")
        idf_path = os.path.join(self.chatbot.main_path, "core/save/idf.sav")
        vocab_path = os.path.join(self.chatbot.main_path, "core/save/vocab.json")

        not_trained = self.chatbot.generator.load_model(model_path, idf_path, vocab_path)

        corpus_samples, self.chatbot.json_dict = self.chatbot.corpus_loader.load(
            corpus_name, not_trained 
        )

        if not_trained:
            self.chatbot.generator.train_vectorizer(corpus_samples)
            self.chatbot.generator.train(corpus_samples)

            self.chatbot.generator.save_model(model_path, idf_path, vocab_path)


    def process(self, **kwargs) -> str:
        input_text = kwargs["InputText"]
        user_text = kwargs["UserText"]
        user_data = kwargs["UserData"]

        text = self.chatbot.generator(input_text)
        self.learn(user_text, user_data["info"])

        if not re.search("[a-zA-Z]", text):
            text = "NoContext"

        text = self.replace_labels(text, self.chatbot.json_dict["structures"])
        text = self.replace_labels(text, user_data["info"])

        #print(type(input_text))
        #text = input_text #Test INPUT

        decision_alg(self,input_text)


        #text = "esto es lo que devuelvo" #Test OUTPUT

        return text


    def decision_alg(self, input_text) -> str:
        i = False

        positive_words = []
        negative_words = []

        #En los puntos .txt deben estar cada palabra y un Enter, por eso agregamos el /n al input, y en la ultima palabra del .txt poner un Enter tambien
        pos_path = 'positive.txt'
        neg_path = 'negative.txt'

        with open(pos_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as textfile:
            #positive_words.extend(textfile.readlines() + [""])
            positive_words.extend(textfile.readlines())
        #print(positive_words)

        with open(neg_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as textfile:
            #negative_words.extend(textfile.readlines() + [""])
            negative_words.extend(textfile.readlines())
        #print(negative_words)

        patron = r"(?:que sugieres|que eliges|que elegirias|te quedarias con|eligirias|selecciona|selecciona entre|decides|que decides)\s*((?:\w+\s*)+) o\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"

        m = re.search(patron, input_text, re.IGNORECASE)
             
        try:
            wordA, wordB = m.groups()

            wordA = wordA.strip()
            wordB = wordB.strip()

            wordA = wordA + "\n"
            wordB = wordB + "\n"


            if wordA in positive_words and wordB in positive_words:
                answer_num = random.randint(1, 2) #numero inicial y final del rango del cual queremos generar numeros

                if answer_num == 1:
                    text = "No estoy segura, ya que ambas son buenas opciones"
                elif answer_num == 2:
                    text = "Creo que elijo, ", str(random.choice([wordA, wordB])).rstrip() #pongo el metodo "rstrip" para eliminar el carácter de salto de línea ("\n")


            elif wordA in positive_words and wordB in negative_words:
                text = "Creo que elijo", wordA.rstrip()

            elif wordA in negative_words and wordB in positive_words:
                text = "Creo que elijo", wordB.rstrip()

            elif wordA in negative_words and wordB in negative_words:
                answer_num = random.randint(1, 2) #numero inicial y final del rango del cual queremos generar numeros

                if answer_num == 1:
                    text = "No estoy segura, ya que ambas son malas opciones"
                elif answer_num == 2:
                    text = "Aunque ambas son malas opciones creo que elijo, ", str(random.choice([wordA, wordB])).rstrip()


            else:

                if not wordA in positive_words or wordA in negative_words:
                    if wordB in positive_words or wordB in negative_words:
                        text = "Lo siento, pero no puedo elegir si no conozco que es la palabra " + wordA.rstrip()
                        i = True
                    elif not wordB in positive_words or wordB in negative_words:
                        if i == False:
                            text = "Lo siento pero no puedo elegir si no conozco ninguna de esas palabras"
                            i = True
                        else:
                            pass

                if not wordB in positive_words or wordB in negative_words:
                    if wordA in positive_words or wordA in negative_words:
                        text = "Lo siento, pero no puedo elegir si no conozco que es la palabra " + wordB.rstrip()
                    elif not wordA in positive_words or wordA in negative_words:
                        if i == False:
                            text = "Lo siento pero no puedo elegir si no conozco ninguna de esas palabras"
                        else:
                            pass

            i = False
            pass


        except AttributeError:
            pass

        return text
```

Si quito `decision_alg(self,input_text)` y no llamo a la función el bot de Discord anda, pero si le pongo esto falla.
La idea es que retorne un text con el string que responderá de output, pero en caso de que se diga esa estructura debe responder del modo que esa función de selección lo define.

De no ser así deja pasar la variable text con el valor que le dieron antes de pasar por esa función `decision_alg(self,input_text)`.

¿Que debo hacer para evitar estos errores y que pueda responder bien?

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 105, in on_message
    await self.send_response(message)
  File "main.py", line 79, in send_response
    response, embed = self.create_response(message)
  File "main.py", line 60, in create_response
    response = ChatBot(message.content, str(message.author.id))
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Desktop\g ver 27-02\SmartBot-main\core\smartbot.py", line 51, in __call__
    output = module.process(
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Desktop\g ver 27-02\SmartBot-main\core\modules\bot_brain.py", line 73, in process
    decision_alg(self,input_text)
NameError: name 'decision_alg' is not defined
```

Tras poner  self.decision_alg(input_text) , me tira esto:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 105, in on_message
    await self.send_response(message)
  File "main.py", line 79, in send_response
    response, embed = self.create_response(message)
  File "main.py", line 60, in create_response
    response = ChatBot(message.content, str(message.author.id))
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Desktop\g ver 27-02\SmartBot-main\core\smartbot.py", line 51, in __call__
    output = module.process(
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Desktop\g ver 27-02\SmartBot-main\core\modules\bot_brain.py", line 73, in process
    self.decision_alg(input_text)
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Desktop\g ver 27-02\SmartBot-main\core\modules\bot_brain.py", line 168, in decision_alg
    return text
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: `self.decision_alg`

Comment: Puse self.decision_alg(input_text)
y me da el error que puse en la actualizacion de la pregunta. Se te ocurre algo?

Comment: El error es claro: estás usando `text` sin haberlo inicializado previamente. Distribuye algunos `print(text)` en esa función para asegurarte de que lo estas inicializando.